# Highstock total on navigator range

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to display a total of the data shown on the chart (and respects the navigator 'zoom' settings)?

I'm charting electricity usage so a total per range (let's say there's a peak usage of 20 minutes or so, and i set the navigator to that range) would be a nice thing to have.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch afterSetExtremes event and calculate points from range.

http://jsfiddle.net/TdFjy/

```
xAxis: {
            events: {
                afterSetExtremes: function () {
                    var counter = 0,
                        min = this.min,
                        max = this.max;

                    $.each(chart.series[0].options.data, function (i, point) {
                        if (point[0] >= min && point[0] <= max) counter++;
                    });

                    $('#report').html(counter);

                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works quite well on the fiddle, however in my environment i get unpredictable results. Calculating the total for the entire chart works, however on a narrow range none off the points seem to fall between min and max..